# transfering C++ code from one programme to another

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libraries

So, my friend told me he managed to build his own ["Enigma Machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine), but he used a programme that doesn't work on my Windows version.

I installed Microsoft's visual studio yesterday and can't get his code to work on mine's. I'm still very young to coding, I was hoping somebody here could help me. I believe the problem lays on the libraries, I've already tried every I know, but I'm not sure what I have to do more, it gives me tons of errors, and ignores precompiled headers.

Here's the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "string"
#include "stdafx.h" //I added this library because vstudio asked me to do so..?
#include "algorithm"

using namespace std;
int i, j, l, r1, r2, r3, n1, n2, n3, n4, rII, rIII;

string msg;

int rotor1[26] = { 4,10,12,5,11,6,3,16,21,25,13,19,14,22,24,7,23,20,18,15,0,8,1,17,2,9 };
int rotor2[26] = { 0,9,3,10,18,8,17,20,23,1,11,7,22,19,12,2,16,6,25,13,15,24,5,21,14,4 };
int rotor3[26] = { 1,3,5,7,9,11,2,15,17,19,23,21,25,13,24,4,8,22,6,0,10,12,20,18,16,14 };
int reflec[26] = { 24,17,20,7,16,18,11,3,15,23,13,6,14,10,12,8,4,1,5,25,2,22,21,9,0,19 };
char base[26] = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };
void RotorInput() {
    cout << "Input initial positions (0 to 25):\n";
    cout << "First rotor: ";
    cin >> r1;
    cout << "Second rotor: ";
    cin >> r2;
    cout << "Third rotor: ";
    cin >> r3;
}
void RotorInitialization() {
    rotate(rotor1, rotor1 + r1, rotor1 + 26);
    rotate(rotor2, rotor2 + r2, rotor2 + 26);
    rotate(rotor2, rotor2 + r2, rotor2 + 26);
}
void MessageInput() {
    cout << "Input your message/code:\n";
    getline(cin, msg);
    getline(cin, msg);
}
void Encription() {
    l = msg.size();
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {

    }
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

        if (msg.at(i) == ' ') {
            cout << " ";
        }
        else {
            int x = distance(base, find(base, base + 26, msg.at(i)));
            n1 = rotor1[x];
            n2 = rotor2[n1];
            n3 = rotor3[n2];
            n4 = reflec[n3];
            n3 = distance(rotor3, find(rotor3, rotor3 + 26, n4));
            n2 = distance(rotor2, find(rotor2, rotor2 + 26, n3));
            n1 = distance(rotor1, find(rotor1, rotor1 + 26, n2));
            cout << base[n1];

            rII = (i + r2 + 1) % 26;
            rIII = (i + r3 + 1) % 676;

            rotate(rotor1, rotor1 + 1, rotor1 + 26);

            if (rII == 0) {
                rotate(rotor2, rotor2 + 1, rotor2 + 26);
            }
            else {}

            if (rIII == 0) {
                rotate(rotor3, rotor3 + 1, rotor3 + 26);
            }
            else {}
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    RotorInput();
    RotorInitialization();
    MessageInput();
    Encription();
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with the first error and solve it, then recompile and repeat. You can post the first error here but be prepared to get flamed by SO denizens. :)

Comment: For all the includes you have except `stdafx.h` use `<name>` note the brackets (so.. `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: You want `#include <iostream>` rather than `#include "iostream"`, and so on for all the others. (Except `stdafx.h` which should be as you have it.)

Comment: Just tried and it got even worse, it says I can't open source file "stdafx.h"

Comment: Wow what the hell, the malware warning I mentioned below only opens when stdafx.h is in the beggining of the code.

????

Comment: Just remove the #include stdafx.h. Works for me on VS2015.

Comment: when I do that it skips all precompiled headers, wth

Comment: but then I get only one error, which is "did you forget to add stdafx.h?"

Comment: The only error I'm getting now is that "getline" is undefined, I have now idea what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody who ends up here after searching google, HEUR/QVM19.1.Malware.Gen is a 360 Total Security (antivirus) false positive. Just whitelist the VS folder.

My problem laid on the fact that my code didn't start with #include "stdafx.h", and when it did my virus had the program flagged as malware. That was the reason of all this mess. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The first of all, precompiled header include should be the first line in your source file.

In addition, I would replace in all the standard library includes by `"` by `<` or `>` respectively to opening or closing quote.

Comment: yeah I had already tried that but it got even worse, now it won't even open the stdafx.h! Also, the errors are pretty weird, they don't recognize cout's and cin's and I can't define the variable "msg" as a string, that's why I thought it had to do with the headers.

And damn, this is happening again: <http://i.imgur.com/7GwevMF.jpg>

It happens whenever I try to run the compiler... yesterday I reinstalled it and I thought I had it fixed... my anti-virus can't find anything :(

Comment: @TugaNid `#include "stafx.h"`anyway have to be the first line, that is how it works.

Comment: apparently that only happens when my stdafx.h is in the first line of the code...  thought had it fixed

Comment: @TugaNid, paste errors without your anti-virus software.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I whitelist it?

Comment: @TugaNid, just copy and paste VC++ build log. Regarding to your antivirus I have nothing to recommend

Comment: ok, now it only happens if I use stdafx.h with the other compilers

Comment: Yay, now the only error I'm getting is:

Comment: " 'getline': identifier not found "
and "identifier getline is undefined"

But it only happens to one of the getline's.

The compilers I'm using are
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

Comment: @TugaNid, try to move all includes to `stdafx.h` and only include it to your source file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what that means